# C++ If statement problem - displaying wrong info

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am having issues with my program displaying information from different if statements when they shouldn't be.
http://i53.tinypic.com/1zyx68.png

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main( )
{
    string smreturn = "";
    string jointsingle = "";
    double income = 0.00;
double taxedincome = 0.00;
{
cout << "\nPlease enter your taxable income: ";
cin >> income;
while (income <= 0)
{
    cout << "\n Please enter a valid positive taxable income: ";
    cin >> income;
}
cout << "\n";
cout << "\nPlease press m if married and filing for a joint return, or s if filing for a single return: ";
cin >> smreturn;
            while (!(smreturn =="m") && !(smreturn =="M") && !(smreturn =="s") && !(smreturn =="S"))
{
    cout << "\nPlease press m if married and filing for a joint return,\n or s if filing for a single return: ";
    cin >> smreturn;
}

if (smreturn == "m" || "M")
{
    if (income >= 0 && income <= 1726)
    {
        taxedincome = income * .023;
    }
    if (income >= 1727 && income <= 3450)
    {
        taxedincome = (income - 1727) * .033 + 40;
    }
    if (income >= 3451 && income <= 5176)
    {
        taxedincome = (income - 3450) * .042 + 97;
    }
    if (income >= 5177 && income <= 6900)
    {
        taxedincome = (income - 5176) * .052 + 169;
    }
    if (income > 8626)
    {
        taxedincome = (income - 8626) * .07 + 362;
    }
        cout << "\nYour taxable income is:$" << (income);
cout << "\nAnd you are filing a joint return";
cout << "\nYour income tax will be:$" << (taxedincome);
cout << "\n";

}
if (smreturn == "s"||"S")
{
    if (income >= 0 && income <= 863)
    {
        taxedincome = (income * .023);
    }
    if (income >= 864 && income <= 1726)
    {
        taxedincome = (income - 863) * .033 + 20;
    }
    if (income >= 1727 && income <= 2588)
    {
        taxedincome = (income - 1726) * .042 + 48;
    }
    if (income >= 2589 && income <= 3450)
    {
        taxedincome - (income - 2588) * 0.052 + 85;
    }
    if (income >= 3451 && income <= 4313)
    {
        taxedincome - (income - 3450) * 0.06 + 129;
    }
    if (income > 4313)
        {
            taxedincome - (income - 4313) * 0.07 + 181;
}
        cout << "\nYour taxable income is:$" << (income);
cout << "\nAnd you are filing a single return";
cout << "\nYour income tax will be:$" << (taxedincome);
cout << "\n";
}
}           cout << "\n";
string returninfo;
if (smreturn == "s" || "S")
{
    returninfo == "single return";
}
else
{
    returninfo == "joint return";
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

It is displaying the info from both If statements, saving taxedincome as a single return for a joint return.

Comment: You say "both" if statements.  There are 14 if statements.

Comment: What is displayed if the income is 1726.50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (smreturn == "m" || "M")
```

should be

```
if ( (smreturn == "m") || (smreturn == "M") )
```

And mistakes like these in few other conditions. If you need to compare, you need to repeat it for each identifier in the `if` condition.

Answer (score 3):

Your if statement is wrong:

```
if (smreturn == "m" || "M")
```

Try this:

```
if ((smreturn == "m") || (smreturn == "M"))
```

The same issue is with this statement:

```
if (smreturn == "s"||"S")
```

Fix it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You error is in:

```
if (smreturn == "m" || "M")
```

You need create two conditionals when you use || (OR). Example:

```
if (age == 15 || yearOfBirth == 1996) {
    std::cout << "Happy!" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "Sad!" << std::endl;
}
```

You can use the && (AND) in the same mode.

**Recommendation:**

Don't use

```
using namespace std;
```

Isn't a good pratice. Every function of the STD you will use

```
std::function
```

Example:

```
std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
```

The "endl" is the clear buffer and add "\n".

Answer (score 0):

`smreturn == "m" || "M"` is always true, because `"M"` will implicitly be converted to `true`.

You probably want `smreturn == "m" || smreturn == "M"` .

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant:

```
if ((smreturn == "m") || (smreturn == "M"))
```

The equality operator tests for equality.  You were using it as a kind of set membership test.  If would be great to be able to write

```
if (smreturn in ["m","M"])
```

but that's the preserve of higher level languages.